# jQuery: Add values separated by comma

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add values those are separated by comma.

Tried-

```
$(function(){
    $('#sum').keyup(function(){
    var prevalue=$('#sum').val().split(",");
        for (i=0;i<prevalue.length;i++){
            prevalue+=prevalue[i];
             $('h1').html(prevalue);
}

    });

});
```

This array goes infinite and doesn't loop values.

How can I add values seperated by comma?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrdJ8/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are modifying the variable `prevalue` (shared by the loop condition) inside the loop where you check for length each time as a loop condition. And each time it adds something to it inside the loop so it goes on an on. It used to be an `array` and after adding the string to it, it coerses to `string` from `array` and then on wards it checks for the length of the string and you keep on appending to it, it goes on and on.

Try:

```
$(function(){
    $('#sum').keyup(function(){
    var prevalue=$('#sum').val().split(","), sum = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<prevalue.length;i++){
            sum += parseInt(prevalue[i], 10) || 0; //<--- Use a parseInt to cast it or use parseFloat

         }
     $('h1').html(sum); //<-- move it to out of the loop
    });
 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TqhvH/)**

Your code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sum').keyup(function () {
        var prevalue = $('#sum').val().split(","); //<-- Iteration 1 prevalue is an array
        for (i = 0; i < prevalue.length; i++) { //iteration1 : it looks for array.length
            prevalue += prevalue[i]; //Changes the variable shared by the loop to string from array and string also has its length. And next time onwards it adds to itself a char from the string and length increases and loop goes infinitely.
            $('h1').html(prevalue); //<-- Doesn't make any sense here.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you mean length of string goes infinite after first iteration? How can it be possible?

Comment: @Manoz 200%... :) Did you not understand with my explanation? You are modifying the variable used in the loop condition. and you append a char to it right after first iteration, so then it checks for new length, and it goes infinitely. Just place a console.log( and break it after 10 iteration manually)

Comment: so it is parsing problem due to string typecast to integer. Right?

Comment: @Manoz Not just parsing problem, you shouldn't modify the variable used in loop condition as well which is a risky stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I could see it in console. Excellent!

Comment: you might want to consider replacing `sum += parseInt(prevalue[i], 10);` with `sum += parseInt(prevalue[i], 10) || 0;`. That way when the value of `#sum` ends in a comma (as it occasionally will as people type) you'll still get a number value for `sum`. Just a thought.

Comment: @BYossarian  Thats an excellent thought, not when comma (which will be handled by split anyways) but if it is an non numeric string which results in NaN... Updated my answer as well...

Comment: @PSL yeah, i know split will take care of the commas, what I meant was that when `$('#sum').val()` equals something like `"2,34,"` then split will produce an array whose last member will be the empty string. When this gets passed to `parseInt` it'll return `NaN` and this will then set `sum` to `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

**You have two problems:**

1.You iterrate over the value you change, and every interation you make the value longer, and therefore its `length` is increasing and making your loop infinite

2.When you use `+=` operator with `string` on the `sum` variable it is translated as string concatenation. in order to translate it as int increment, use `parseInt()`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#sum').keyup(function(){
    var prevalue=$('#sum').val().split(",");
        sum = 0;
        for (i=0;i<prevalue.length;i++){
            sum+=parseInt(prevalue[i]);
}
        $('h1').html(sum);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sum').keyup(function () {
        var finalvalue = 0;
        var prevalue = $('#sum').val().split(",");
        for (i = 0; i < prevalue.length; i++) {
            finalvalue += parseInt(prevalue[i]);
        }
        $('h1').html(finalvalue);
    })
});
```

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Yjrj/2/)**

This ->  `prevalue+=prevalue[i];` frezes your browser.

- I added a new variable `finalvalue` to get the sum or the values of `prevalue` inside the loop.
- Your array, generated by split, has strings. So I used `parseInt()` to get numbers that you can add, otherwise `+=` will work as a string concatenation.
- I removed the `$('h1').html(finalvalue);` from inside the loop, no need for it to render on each loop. So I put it after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `prevalue` while you're still operating on it. Use another variable instead.

```
$(function(){
    $('#sum').keyup(function(){
    var prevalue=$('#sum').val().split(","), value = 0;
        for (i=0;i<prevalue.length;i++){
            value+=parseInt(prevalue[i], 10);
             $('h1').html(value);
        }  

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better to handle what you are doing, as an addition to the main problem that you had, which was modifying the same array which was supposed to contain the array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sum').keyup(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#sum').val().split(',').map(function(n) {
            if(!n) return;
            sum += parseInt(n);
            return sum;
        });
        $('#result').text(sum);
    });
});
```

See the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/achrome/UVUb4/) here.

Comment: Why do you think using a `map` better? Also the way you have it implemented doesn't even utilize the return of map. Also it is Ecma5 you need a shim for older browsers? and also this could be slower considered to just using a for loop for this purpose.

Comment: Map is marginally better than using the for loop. You can see the results here. http://jsperf.com/achrome-for-vs-map

I agree with the shim for older browsers, and the return is done this way to avoid `NaN` from being displayed just after a comma is entered.

Comment: Na, you need to cache the length in for-loop and check this http://jsperf.com/achrome-for-vs-map/2 , it is intermittent. Plus for this purpose if you thinnk of using a map then forEach would be better as you are not utilizing the map's return(which is generally used for transforming array of objects to a array of objects with changes)

Comment: Plus sorry your benchmark doesn't even go inside the keyup., you need to put it outside and set up and array,

Comment: Even with caching jsperf shows me that map achieves higher ops/sec. However, I get your point about the general purpose of map, but I don't rigidly agree with it.

Comment: Sorry, it was still running the old rev. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Comment: Not really remove all unwanted stuffs frmo bench mark and just have iteration and sum up , for is always faster i guess check http://jsperf.com/achrome-for-vs-map/2 and the reason in your benchmark map was faster because of jquery .html() v/s .text(). So you weren't fair with for logic.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you use the same variable for the values and the sum. Try something like this:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#sum').keyup(function() {
        var values = $('#sum').val().split(",");
        var sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            // At this point values[i] is still a string, so you need to parse it to float or int
            sum += parseFloat(values[i]);
        }

        $('h1').html(sum);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try with this one...........

```
$(function(){
    $('#sum').keyup(function(){
    var prevalue=$('#sum').val().split(",");
    var value = '';
        for (i=0;i<prevalue.length;i++){
            value+=prevalue[i];
             $('h1').html(value);
        }  

    });

});
```